# Spatial Join in Entity Framework

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, spatial

I want to write a join statement in LINQ using the dbgeography's "Intersects" method (I am using EF June 2011 CTP). The problem is if I write something like this:

```
var joinQuery = from spQ in spatialTableQuery
                    join mnQ in MainQuery
                    on spQ.Polygon.Intersects(mnQ.PointGeography) equals 1
```

I get the following error:

> The name 'mnQ' is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'.  Consider
>   swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'.

In SQL I have written a similar query as below so I know SQL suppports it:

```
SELECT  * FROM   Address a 
INNER JOIN  SPATIALTABLE b
WITH(INDEX(geog_sidx))
ON b.geom.STIntersects(a.PointGeography) = 1
```

Comment: Can you try it in a Where clause (ala SQL-82) instead of using a join clause? The join clause translates into a Join extension method and mnQ isn't an input parameter on the left side selector.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
var joinQuery = 
   from spQ in spatialTableQuery
   from mnQ in MainQuery
   where spQ.Polygon.Intersects(mnQ.PointGeography) = 1
```